# multiple captions on html table

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a table with captions on the left and on the bottom. But as of now I am being able to put only one caption on one table.

this is the code of my html table.

```
<table style="border: 1px solid ">
<caption style="caption-side:left;">this is supposed to be on the x axis</caption>

    <caption style="caption-side:bottom;">this is supposed to be on the y axis</caption>
<tr>
    <th>animals</th>
    <th>food</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>cat</td>
    <td>milk</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>dog</td>
    <td>meat</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

can any one help me to get this fixed? help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Just you can't. `table` can have only one `caption`. Moreover even `caption-side` can be only `top` or `bottom` (your `left` value is wrong) so you can't put it in Y axes.

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=multiple+captions+on+html+table&oq=multiple+captions+on+html+table&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8